# Не могу изменить изменить атрибут в родительском классе через super

Tags: java

Коллеги, где то туплю, помогите. Ошибка.

```
 class myOld{
public int oldN =1;
}
 class myNew extends myOld{
 super.oldN=2;
}

public class JavaApplication16 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        myNew i = new myNew();
        System.out.println(i.oldN);
    }

}
```

Comment: class myNew extends myOld {
    myNew(){
        super.oldN  = 2;
    }
} если хотите, чтобы переменная изменялась пр создании класса, то добавляйте конструктор. а вообще нужны геттеры сеттеры, а также смотрите правила именования (класс не должен быть с маленькой буквы и т.д.)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyOld{
   public int oldN =1;
}
class MyNew extends MyOld{
   public MyNew(){
     super.oldN=2;
   }
}
```